# Выдаёт ошибку при заполнении (sqlite3)базы данных пользователями

Tags: python, sqlite3

У меня есть экономический дискорд-бот, которого я хочу загрузить на один из серверов, на котором 3500 участников. Проблема в том, что когда я загружаю бота на этот сервер, база данных заполняется не полностью(не больше 580 участников), хотя я заливал его на другой сервер(90 участников), и всё работало исправно, 3 дня подряд гуглю, не могу найти решение

Сам код из-за которого выдаёт ошибку:

````
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game('Фармилка гемов'))
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        "name" Text,
        "id" INT,
        "cash" BIGINT, 
        "server_id" INT
    )""")
    connection.commit()

    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shop (
            "role_id" INT,
            "id" INT,
            "cost" BIGINT
    )""")
    connection.commit()

    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, {guild.id})")
                connection.commit()
            else:
                pass
    connection.commit()
    print('Bot connected!')



Ошибка:
```Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "f:\SSD\Python\FinBot\botfn.py", line 48, in on_ready
    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, {guild.id})")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "bly": syntax error
````

Comment: Очевидно `guild.id` у вас содержит значение `bly`, а его нельзя вставить в INT поле.

Comment: Ни малейшего понятия. Из этого куска кода видно, что оно берется из элемента из списка(?) guilds, который хранится в атрибуте объекта `client`. Откуда взялся client и как туда попали объекты guild из этого фрагмента не ясно.

Comment: Я нашёл проблему, всё портило переменная "{member}"

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, всё работает!

Comment: Точно, это еще одна возможность. `member` - объект, `{member}` - строковое представление объекта. Если в строковом представлении есть кавычки, то будет такая ошибка. Вероятно вы хотели взять какое-то поле из объекта member. Ну и еще, не создавайте запрос путем манипуляции со строками, используйте подстановку переменных https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-placeholders

Comment: Благодарю вас!!